# How to format JSON so I can allow the file to carry values not needed for a graph

Tags: json

I probably don't understand the JSON format enough but here goes. I have a graph whose values are based on a database that keeps a node id, which node is following that node and which node is followed by that node. The graph requires a JSON format as follows:

```
nodes: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",],edges: [["1","7"],["2","3"],["1","4"],["7","1"],["4","3"],["5","3"],["4","8"],["9","1"],["3","2"],["5","2"],["9","4"],["5","80"],["8","4"]}
```

where the nodes are drawn as a node and the edges are the id of the source node and the target node so they can be connected up with a line.

However I would also like to be able to manipulate the characteristics of the node using javascript, based on other fields in a record. For example I have a field called size and I would eventually like to change the node colour based on that (each node has one size value).

The problem I have is how to carry the information of eg size in the same JSON as nodes and edges. The graph requires nodes and edges to be rendered. Obviously if I'm going to carry the size field as well it would need to be associated with the  node rather than as another array. Is there a way of doing this in JSON?

Comment: nodes: [{id:"1",size:"something",property:"somethingElse"},{id:"2",...AND SO ON}],edges[[],[],[]]... Did you try to handle your nodes as "objects" instead of just array values... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just have to handle your data as "objects"... Then you give them properties (like ID and SIZE) and you get them with . in js.

For example, you should declare your "array" like an array of objects, like this :

```
var nodes = [{id:"1",size:"big"},{id:"2",size:"small"},{id:"3",size:"huge"},{id:"4",size:"tiny"},{id:"5",size:"normal"}];
```

Then handle it with :

```
console.log(nodes[n].id);
console.log(nodes[n].size);
```

Have a look at this fiddle (and look at console) : 
http://jsfiddle.net/0vkg3tt9/3/

Hope it helps